# Oracle 8i SQL - concatenate strings from different rows

Tags: sql, string, oracle, concatenation, oracle8i

I need to concatenate strings from different rows, as below.
The number of rows for each NAME is variable and its range is unknown.

```
NAME  COLOR
Bob   Red
Bob   Blue
Tom   Green
John  Red
John  Yellow
John  Purple
```

Desired output:

```
NAME  COLORS
Bob   RedBlue
Tom   Green
John  RedYellowPurple
```

The limitations I am facing are :

- Oracle 8i (8.1.7.4.0) - I have no control over this and upgrading is
  not an option
- read only access
- can't create...

So basically :

- no CREATE
- no LISTAGG
- no XMLAGG
- no WM_CONCAT
- no Ref Cursor
- no SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH

Am I SOL ?

Comment: Tough one this will be, maybe connect by level and sum? a subquery to count number of colors to each name, and a connect by query with level statement concatenating until it reaches the count.

Comment: How is it even possible to run Oracle 8i nowadays?

Comment: Can you create functions?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I cannot create functions. This is a legacy system from which I'm pulling data. I have absolutely no control over anything. FYI it runs along with a Tcl/Tk front end which isn't being maintained anymore, even though it's in prod for critial daily ops. Moreover there's only one 8i dba left in the company and his hands are full already trying to keep corruption out of this 8i db. But, we're beside the point here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 8i at least supports analytic functions, so you could assign each color value a nominal number with [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/function.htm#86312) or `dense_rank()` (ordering by whatever makes sense to you):

```
select name, color,
  row_number() over (partition by name order by color) as rn
from your_table;
```

and then use a variation on a manual pivot with one `max(decode())` per possible row number:

```
select name,
  max(decode(rn, 1, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 2, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 3, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 4, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 5, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 6, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 7, color))
  -- ...
  as colors
from (
  select name, color,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by color) as rn
  from your_table
)
group by name
order by name;

NAME       COLORS                                                                
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob        BlueRed                                                               
John       PurpleRedYellow                                                       
Tom        Green
```

You said the range is unknown, but even if there are an unlimited number of rows for each name, you're still restricted by the final concatenated string having to be at most 4000 characters - from your knowledge of the actual color values that would give you a maximum usable number. (And you could generate the decode parts automatically as a one-off thing).

You could include delimiters the same way if you needed to:

```
select name,
  max(decode(rn, 1, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 2, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 2, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 3, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 3, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 4, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 4, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 5, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 5, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 6, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 6, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 7, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 7, color))
  || max(decode(rn, 8, ',')) || max(decode(rn, 8, color))
  -- ...
  as colors
from (
  select name, color,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by color) as rn
  from your_table
  where color is not null
)
group by name
order by name;

NAME       COLORS                                                                                 
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob        Blue,Red                                                                               
John       Purple,Red,Yellow                                                                      
Tom        Green
```

I've included a `is not null` filter in the inner query just in case that column is nullable - that ought to prevent empty elements in the final list.

(Not tested in 8i as I can't find an instance that old to spin up, but I don't think this is using anything introduced later...)

Comment: I will test this back at work on Monday. I just checked that row_number() is indeed part of the 8i analytical functions per Oracle's SQL reference, so it should work.

Comment: Okay this would work if we take as an assumption that "color" is made of a relatively small set of unique values. However the value of "rn" really can be infinite, in theory. So this could kind of work but not in all situations. I do understand that the bigger "rn" gets, the closer you get to hitting the 4000 limit. However, couldn't someone convert from varchar2 to LONG or CLOB before the concatenation occurs to avoid hitting this limit?